# Синтаксические ошибки в скрипте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот есть скрипт (из юнити, скачано из ассет стора), и в нем выходит 2 ошибки:

```
Assets/Fungus/Scripts/Components/DialogInput.cs(38,10): error CS1513: } expected
```

```
Assets/Fungus/Scripts/Components/DialogInput.cs(180,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Вот сам скрипт: https://pastebin.com/QcgaTCqR
Буду благодарен, за любую помощь!

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально ошибки, приведите код в самом вопросе текстом, а не по ссылке

Comment: Когда у вас нос чешется, вы его ногой чешете? Просто никогда не понимал людей который имея возможность показать свой код с красивыми стилями, с подсветкой в этом сайту, заливают в другой сайт.

Comment: Мне кажется, не стоит засорять вопрос, если скрипт слишком велик. Небольшой участок кода я всегда оформляю прямо в вопросе.

Comment: А ошибки сейчас отформатирую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка находится в этом куске кода:

```
protected virtual void inistilit()
{
    public string[] modes = new string[] { "Disabled", "ClickAnywhere", "ClickOnDialog", "ClickOnButton" };
    public string mode = modes[1];
}
```

Вы не можете использовать модификаторы доступа (`public`) внутри метода.
Может быть стоит вынести объявление этих переменных за пределы метода?

Comment: спасибо) Помогли

Comment: Дело в том, что изначально они были вне метода, а потом возникла необходимость перенести все это дело внутрь. А через 2 часа работы, котелок уже виснет)))